# For which values $\alpha, \ \beta \in \mathbb R $ does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^{\beta}(n)}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I determine for which values $\alpha, \ \beta \in \mathbb R $ does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^\alpha ln^{\beta}(n)}$ converges?

I want to use the integral test to show it, so I proved that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^\alpha ln^{\beta}(x)} \geq 0$ and that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing. but How do I continue from here? I assume that are a lot of cases but is there an easy way to see it directly?

Comment: Do you know the fact that if a positive series $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges?

Comment: The above fact helps you with $\beta$ when $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: Also, $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n)/n^{p} = 0$ whenever $p >0$ so you might use limit comparison test for $\alpha$.

Comment: So what is your guess to the answer?

Comment: @LiChunMin I suggest you to post your first comment as an answer of this question. It's nice comment.

Comment: The quoted fact requires the sequence to be monotonic, which actually the case here. Sorry for missing out the assumption here.

Answer (score 0):

> Fact: Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive monotonically decreasing sequence. Then $\sum a_n $ converges iff $\sum 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges.

This is usually seen in a analysis textbook. The assumption is met by the given sequence. With this fact, we can prove, for example, the series diverges when $\alpha = 1$, $\beta =1$:

Write $a_n = \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$. $b_k = 2^ka_{2^k}$. For each $k \geq 2$,

$$b_k = 2^ka_{2^k} = 2^k \frac{1}{2^k \ln(2^k)} =\frac{1}{k\ln(2)} = \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\frac{1}{k}$$

By p-series test, $\sum b_n = \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\sum 1/k$ diverges. By the quoted fact, $\sum a_n = \sum \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ diverges.

---

We prove the fact above. Say $\{a_n\}$ starts from $n = 2$. For each $k \geq 1$, let $b_k = 2^ka_k$. Also write $A_n = \sum_{i = 2}^n a_i$ and $B_k = \sum_{i = 1}^k b_i$.

$$B_k = 2a_2 +4a_4 + \cdots + 2^{k} a_{2^k}\geq (a_2 + a_3) +(a_4 + a_5+a_6+a_7) + \cdots + (a_{2^k} + \cdots + a_{2^{k+1}-1}) = A_{2^{k+1}-1}$$

$$B_k/2 = a_2 +2a_4 + \cdots + 2^{k-1} a_{2^k}\leq a_2 + (a_3 + a_4) + \cdots +  (a_{2^{k-1}+1} + \cdots + a_{2^{k}}) = A_{2^k}$$

If $\{A_n\}$ is bounded above by $M \in \Bbb{R}$, then for each $k$, $B_k \leq 2A_{2^k}\leq 2M$.

If $\{B_n\}$ is bounded above by $M \in \Bbb{R}$, then for each $k$, $A_n \leq A_{2^{n+1}-1} \leq B_n\leq M$.

A positive series converges iff it is bounded above. And $\{A_n\}$ is bounded above iff $\{B_n\}$ is bounded above. Therefore, the fact follows.